# React Native auth error handle with <View> component

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

i'm handling firebase auth errors and i cant show error message on screen
here is my code;

```
if (error.code === "auth/user-not-found") {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>user not found</Text>
                    <Text>try create a account or check ur mail and passwrd</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
```

but i use alert it works perfectly.
how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some styles in your components so you can see something.

```
if (error.code === "auth/user-not-found") {
            return (
                <View style={{flex: 1, width: "100%", height: "100%", backgroundColor: "#f00"}}>
                    <Text>user not found</Text>
                    <Text>try create a account or check ur mail and passwrd</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
```

I like to try first with full width and height, and with a very basic color (in this case red) so I can watch whats happening in my views. Remember that you can save and metro gonna refresh your app in your emulator/phone.

Comment: @n00b do you have another return after this one?
Maybe thats your problem, if your conditional is always false you would never gonna return your view with texts.
If you can provide more context we can help you more.

Comment: here is my code;
https://i.ibb.co/HBN8y84/err.png